# How to display a ROW based on value in CASE STATEMENT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query as below, and want to display a row only if the value is 1 using CASE. Please can you advice how I can do that

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.AccountID, 
    a.ForeName, 
    a.Surname, 
    a.Gender, 
    CASE 
        WHEN B.Value = '1145' THEN '1' 
        WHEN B.Value = '1007' THEN '2' ELSE '0' 
    END AS Value, 
    b.Address,
     b.Town
FROM 
    Customer a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    AdditionalDetails b
ON 
    b.ID = a.AccountID
```

The result I am getting:

```
 AccountID  ForeName  Surname  Gender NoName  Address Town
  00012       Eric      Manse   Male    0      Porto   Porto
  00013       Peter     Mark    Male    0      Porto   Porto
  00014       Tom       Jerry   Male    0      Porto   Porto
  00014       Tom       Jerry   Male    1      Porto   Porto
  00015       Sarah     Parker  Female  0      Porto   Porto
  00015       Sarah     Parker  Female  1      Porto   Porto
```

If there is a 1 in the CASE statement, it should not display the 0 just the row with the value 1

Comment: Add example data and expected output

Comment: Using `GROUP BY` could offer a solution that removes the need to use `DISTINCT`.  However, I am curious as to why you don't want to use `DISTINCT`?

Comment: `distinct` can only be applied on the entire row.

Comment: Also, please add the tag for the relevant rdbms you are working with - product and version.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is in your query to remove duplicates. So the person who wrote the query expects to find multiple records with the same address and town and value for one customer. Is this even the case? If not, then you can remove `DISTINCT` from your query without changing the results. Have you tried this?

Comment: Or does this query even return the desired result or do you want another result? If so: what does the current result look like and how do you want it different?

Comment: BTW: I suppose ON `b.ID = a.ID` is just a typo? Or is there a 1:1 relation between the two tables?

Comment: So sorry, I have edited my question and made the corrections. I just noticed that my question was wrong.

Comment: Case _expression_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I speculate that you want either `MAX()` or `MIN()`:

```
SELECT c.AccountID, c.ForeName, c.Surname, c.Gender, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN ad.Value = '1145' THEN '1'
                WHEN ad.Value = '1007' THEN '2'
                ELSE '0' 
           END),
      ad.Address, ad.Town
FROM Customer c LEFT OUTER JOIN
     AdditionalDetails ad
     ON c.ID = ad.ID
GROUP BY c.AccountID, c.ForeName, c.Surname, c.Gender, ad.Address, ad.Town;
```

EDIT:

You seem to want prioritization:

```
SELECT cad.*
FROM (SELECT c.AccountID, c.ForeName, c.Surname, c.Gender, 
             ad.Address, ad.Town,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.ACCOUNTID
                                ORDER BY (CASE WHEN ad.Value = '1145' THEN 1
                                               WHEN ad.Value = '1007' THEN 2
                                               ELSE 0'
                                          END) DESC
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM Customer c LEFT OUTER JOIN
           AdditionalDetails ad
           ON c.ID = ad.ID
     ) cad
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you, I just realized that I was asking my question wrong after trying out different solutions. I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

You have altered your question. You are not looking for distinct rows, but you want to rank the rows and only display best matches.

Depending on your exact requirements you'd use `RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER` with an appropriate `ORDER BY` and `PARTITION BY` clause for this.

For instance:

```
select c.*, ad.address, ad.town
from customer c
left join
(
  select
    address,
    town,
    customer_id,
    rank() over (partition by customer_id
                 order by case value when 1145 then 1 when 1007 then 2 else 0 end desc) as rnk
  from additionaldetails
) ad on ad.customer_id = c.id and d.rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try like below

```
 with cte as  (

        SELECT  a.AccountID, a.ForeName, a.Surname, a.Gender,
        b.Address, b.Town,         
        row_number() over(partition by a.AccountID
   order by 
     (CASE WHEN b.Value = '1145' THEN 1 WHEN b.Value = '1007' THEN 2 ELSE 0 
        END) desc) as val
        FROM Customer a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN AdditionalDetails b
        ON b.ID = a.AccountID    
       ) select * from cte where val=1
```